# I am having a permissions error with CircleCI when doing build and test runs (how to fix it)

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

Is the solution related to not having a public access token for the github repository or not having a deploy key? I am new to using DevOps tools like CircleCi so I need some input please as to what might be the issue and what steps I need to fix it. I already created a deploy key at the beginning when I created an account with Circle CI with a passphrase (it asks you to do so but it does give you an option to add more SSH keys which I thought you don't have to do, which I may be wrong about), do I need to add another.

```
#!/bin/sh

Using SSH Config Dir '/home/circleci/.ssh'
git version 2.40.0
Cloning git repository
Cloning into '.'...
Load key "/home/circleci/.ssh/id_rsa": error in libcrypto
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

exit status 128
```

Was expecting my build to work and I have looked online as my setup seems okay for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends if it's a standalone project (new [GitHub App integration](https://circleci.com/docs/github-apps-integration/)) or not (legacy [GitHub OAuth App integration](https://circleci.com/docs/github-integration/)).

If it's the new integration, you need to [manually create and add an SSH key to your project settings](https://circleci.com/docs/github-apps-integration/#project-settings-ssh-keys). That SSH key **should not** have a passphrase.

If it's the legacy integration, then a deploy SSH key is automatically added when you set up the project. But you can then opt to add a user SSH key, as the preferred one.

The solution to your issue will depend on which CircleCI-GitHub integration you're "using".